# Why doesn't rsync over ssh work when placed inside a FOR loop in a batch file?

Tags: windows, ssh, rsync, cygwin, batch

I've placed the ff. code in rsync.bat:

```
for %%A in (%VAR_REMOTE_HOST%) do (
  set VAR_TARGET=%USER%@%%A:%VAR_TARGET_DIR%

  echo Rsync Source Dir: %VAR_SOURCE%
  setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  echo Rsync Target Dir: !VAR_TARGET!
  endlocal

  echo Syncing files...

  rsync -rltgDvzO --chmod=Dugo=rwX,Fugo=rw -e ssh %VAR_SOURCE% %VAR_TARGET%
)
```

where VAR_REMOTE_HOST is a comma-separated list of servers.

It outputs a list of files to rsync, along with permissions, sizes and timestamps.
It even displays an rsync log at the end (sent bytes, received bytes, bytes/sec)
However, the files are not sent to the target. It's as if it ran a dry-run. (but no -n option)

See screenshot here. (http://postimg.org/image/vc0kei1j1/)

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

> It's as if it ran a dry-run. (but no -n option)

Take a look at your rsync line again:

```
rsync -nrltgDvzO
```

I clearly see a `-n` option there...

Comment: Oops. My bad. I copied the line from when I was troubleshooting. I changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit!
Changed %VAR_TARGET% to !VAR_TARGET! and moved endlocal to the end of the loop.

New code:

```
for %%A in (%VAR_REMOTE_HOST%) do (
  set VAR_TARGET=%USER%@%%A:%VAR_TARGET_DIR%

  echo Rsync Source Dir: %VAR_SOURCE%
  setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  echo Rsync Target Dir: !VAR_TARGET!

  echo Syncing files...

  rsync -rltgDvzO --chmod=Dugo=rwX,Fugo=rw -e ssh %VAR_SOURCE% !VAR_TARGET!
  endlocal
)
```